# Finding the eigenfunctions of a large dataset - Too much ram

Tags: python, ram, covariance, hpc, eigenvalue

I have a python script that determines the covariance and eigenfunctions of each sample in my dataset but it requires too much RAM. What approach should I take? Should I consider using another programming language like C?

I have access to my University's HPC and I have previously successfully run the script on a smaller dataset before. The issue is that this time my dataset is much larger (2.6TB) and each sample are also larger (1.3GB). I managed to attempt to run this script with 256GB of RAM (the highest amount I could ask) but it failed.

This script uses Numpy and SciPy to find the covariance and eigenfunctions of my dataset.

```
def analysis(meanX, meanY, result):
    # Finding the fluctuation of the data 
    fluX = []
    fluY = []
    for i in result:
        df = pd.read_csv(i)
        Vx = df['Vx'].values - meanX
        fluX = np.append(fluX, Vx)
        Vy = df['Vy '].values - meanY
        fluY = np.append(fluY, Vy)
    flu = []
    flu = np.append(fluX, fluY)
    n_snapshots = len(result)
    n_data = len(Vx)
    flu = np.reshape(flu, (n_snapshots, n_data*2)) 
    cov = np.cov(flu.T)
    eigenvalue, eigenvector = scipy_eigenvalue(cov)
    return eigenvalue, eigenvector

def scipy_eigenvalue(cov):
    eigenvalue, eigenvector = eigsh(cov, k=10)
    sum = np.sum(eigenvalue)
    return eigenvalue, eigenvector
```

This script however takes too much RAM and I am hoping to hear ideas about how to reduce the RAM demand.

Edit: I realised I should make an update for posterity sake. I have chosen to use Scikit's implementation of the PCA (POD), which uses Halko's paper 'Finding structure with randomness: Probabilistic algorithms for constructing approximate matrix decompositions'.

This method doesn't eat up the RAM and is much faster.

Comment: Absolutely consider using another programming language like C.

Comment: @ScottHunter: if, as seems likely, the problem is that OP is simply trying to stuff too much data into available memory, what material impact would switching to C have ?  I'd have thought an *out-of-core* algorithm would be the next stage (albeit that that might be better written in C than in Python).

Comment: How substantial is the ram usage improvement on C compared to Python? I'm asking as I don't want to commit to writing C code without knowing how well the improvement should generally be.

Comment: It is more a matter of having more control over RAM usage; it also means having to explicitly manage things that Python handled for you.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll see what libraries are available in C and search for out-of-core algorithms relevant to my problem in the meantime. Thanks!